# Azure DevOps shows Enterprise subscription but the person does not have a Visual Studio license

Tags: azure-devops, subscription

I have some users in Azure DevOps who show as having a Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription for their Access Level but they are not assigned a Visual Studio license. I am trying to figure out how this can be.

[image: Image Requested on 2/1/2022]

Comment: Azure DevOps Server? Azure DevOps cloud?

Comment: Azure DevOps Cloud

Answer (score 1):

You assign the license, but it's only validated upon sign-in on Azure DevOps cloud. When they try to sign in and don't have a valid enterprise license, the user will be downgraded to Stakeholder access.

A user could also have a subscription on another email address and have configured an alternate email for their subscription.

You assign the license, but it's never validated but upon a true-up/audit you may need to pay for them after the fact on Azure DevOps Server.

Comment: We are using Azure DevOps Cloud so for new team members, it is validated once they sign in. Many of the people in the system who have Enterprise licenses have been around a long time. I am not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Every time they sign in their license is validated. If Azure DevOps finds an associated subscription, it will keep them active. Or downgrade them to Stakeholder.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I understand that it validates their license when they log in. We have people listed as an Enterprise access level in Azure DevOps who are not assigned an Enterprise license. I have asked a few to see if they have an alternate email set up and they do not.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: What would you like a screenshot of?

Comment: The users panel of the organization showing the assigned license.

Comment: I uploaded an image in the original post. According to our IT team who manages our MSDN/Visual Studio Subscriptions, this person does not have a Visual Studio license.

Comment: Screenshot says there is a subscription and it was validated. So someone, somewhere is paying for a subscription for this user.

Comment: That is the perplexing thing. We as a company are not, the individual is not, so unless a former employer of the person (one person from over 15 years ago because they have been with us at least that long) I cannot figure out who would be paying for it.

Comment: Contact support I suppose